# Wampserver not starting apache server

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver

I am using wampserver to start apache and mysql servers. However, only mysql server is getting started. In EventViewer I observed below error.

```
Faulting application path: E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin\php5ts.dll
```

Infact, my wampserver is in D:\ drive whereas event viewer is complaining about files in E drive.

I forgot what changes I made in the past and now unable to find the location where I can configure correct path to apache server in wampserver.

Comment: it looks like you have installed wamp in `E` earlier and now installed in `D`, check both "wamp" folder in both drives, if found, uninstall wamp by "uninstall a program"  and make sure delete "wamp" folder(manually) and install wamp again

Comment: Or you have 2 Apache web servers installed

Comment: I have installed wamp server in D drive earlier and in E later. That could be the reason it is pointing to e:\ files. I started httpd and mysqld separately from respective folder locations in D drive and they are running now.